How to combine two scikit-learn sub-models into an ensemble using an if condition and save it to a pickle file?
I have trained two scikit-learn models using an IF condition (resulting in two training sets based on defined criteria on the X1 feature). How can I integrate this if condition with these two trained models into a single holistic model and save it to a pickle file?
